# Offering bounty on question with less views

Tags: discussion, support

I asked this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1059617/creating-a-text-file-based-on-inputs-from-other-text-files) which has like 23 views till now. Even with such low view rate I have two **close** request against the question. I have done my homework, but still may be the users think that my question is still not good enough (well-worded) or does not show enough research effort

My question is would it be immoral to offer bounty on my question to lure more people to view / push them answer for the sake of bounty?

Comment: Offering a bounty on a bad question is not recommended. Your question is too broad and in any case is more of a programming question, which is off-topic on [su].

Comment: Offering a bounty on a bad question will result in one of two things.  A substandard answers being provide because of the reputation, or no additional answers and the question after the bounty expires still is closed.  You currently have feedback on your question, you should improve the quesiton, before you place the bounty.

Comment: @Ramhound, *A substandard answers being provide because of the reputation*.  Yes, this is very much possible. I've cleaned up and deleted the question

Comment: You shouldn't delete questions just improve them, users who delete questions, end of being unable to ask questions

Comment: @Ramhound. I agree. But my question is way too far from making it specific. It would take quite some time for me to improve on that based on my learning curve. Further, I was given the `peer-pressure` badge for deleting a question with -3 votes - which already is a bad thing!

Comment: @Prasanna - Its entirely up to you.  Questions, require a great deal of time on your part, in order for them to be good questions.  Before you hit that submit button be sure your next question, is the very best it can be, that first revision.  We all miss something, so revisions exist for that reason, but a good question is good from the very first revision.

Comment: @Ramhound, IMHO, low quality questions (like the one I posted) are mostly due to the fact that a person assumes when he/she thinks that the question must be a fairly straight forward and simple one. It dawns only when we get to see specific comments (in my case as commented by MattDo and Sathya) that the question is a big topic (`too-broad`) in itself and there is a lot of home-work to be done.

Comment: @Prasanna - My sole purpose is to warn you from making a habit of removing "bad" questions and/or answers.  That isn't the correct solution to the problem, questions which are improved are more often accepted, then not accepted after being improved.

Comment: @Ramhound. Got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question currently has three close votes against it, one of which is for the *too broad* reason. (For the record, I'm not one of the close voters.) I would agree: requests for scripts do not usually make for useful questions because they're applicable only to the person who asked the question, and we're about building knowledge, not doing stuff for people. *Too broad* doesn't describe that perfectly, but it seems to be the de facto close reason for such questions.

There's nothing wrong with offering a bounty on a question that didn't get enough attention/answers - that's the purpose of the bounty system! However, don't expect that the bounty will stop your question from being closed. Whenever I see a close-worthy question with a bounty, I raise a custom mod flag. Every time I've done that, the question was immediately closed or migrated, as appropriate. I believe the rep for the bounty is refunded, but I'm not sure if that's a guarantee.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. This is the main reason why, I wanted to know if it is appropriate to offer a bounty on such a question. Your answer helps. To clean up things, I have deleted that question.

Comment: I don't go out of my way to close a question with a bounty, but I recall a case where somebody wanted more attention to their question which did have close votes, and I offered a bounty to that question.  What ended up happening was, the author who complained about not getting attention never followed up on ANY of the comments, and the bounty expired.  I ended up after the bounty ended just voting to close that question, because at the end of the day, the question still had the same problems and wasn't answered.  So what Ben says is true a bounty won't prevent a bad question from being closed.